# What do I need in order to use listAll for Firebase storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use [this code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files) to get a list of all files in a firebase storage directory, but android studio can't recognise the listAll method ("cannot resolve method listAll").
My firebase storage is using storage rules version 2.

Comment: Most likely cause is in my answer below. If that's not it, you'll have to show the [minimal code that can be used to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using a version of the Firebase Storage SDK for Android that doesn't contain this method yet.

Be sure that your [Firebase Storage SDK version is 18.1](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#version_1810) or later.